# What should our domain name be?

Tags: discussion, community

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

### Note:

We are closing this domain naming thread. It is asking the *entirely* wrong question. See this blog post for details: [Domain Names: Wrong Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/)

We're going to keep the name tex.stackexchange.com. But we WILL be setting up redirects from the more "popular" domains names (e.g. seasonedadvice.com to cooking.stackexchange.com, basicallymoney.com to money.stackexchange.com, and others as we go through the list).

New question: "**Write and Elevator Pitch / Tagline!**"

[**Click here to contribute ideas and vote.**](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

*[original message text below]*

---

This is one of ["The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/), so I'll get the ball rolling by asking it.

Comment: As Joel mentions [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/), names that appear to be parked might still be worth buying. Also, I recommend that each post containing a domain name have the name on a separate line, prefaced with a `#` for easy visibility. (As Scott and John have done)

Comment: One thing to remember is that the name should be catchy. It should be something even casual/new users can remember, that you can say out loud and have people 1. understand what you're referring to, and 2. type directly into their browser. Which means multi-word names are bad, plural (texnician*s*.com) is probably iffy too, and other such "extras" you might or might not remember, hear or notice. A progammer is able to remember a name like StackOverflow. What name will a TeX user remember?

Comment: Multi-word names are not necessarily bad (exhibit A: Stack Overflow), but the words do have to be part of a coherent unit.

Comment: Can we close this now?  TeXnique.com is now 20 pts ahead of the underspecified #2, and voting in this thread has kind of petered out.

Comment: I suggest **MovingArguments.com**

Answer (score 45):

TeXnique

## TeXnique.com

I love the TeX/Tech play on words. At least **this one is available**.

Comment: +1:  Sounds good, easy to remember, fits with the corny play-on-words, and implies that the site is made up of professionals rather than support personnel.

Comment: Yeah, I like it. +1

Comment: I love this name. Just one suggestion I have, so that people don't get misled by the domain name and think this is only about TeX, is to have a very inclusive subtitle/slogan, maybe something similar to the current "For expert users of TeX, LaTeX and friends".

Comment: This domain name is now taken... BY **STACK OVERFLOW INTERNET SERVICES**!

Comment: It's a very nice artificial word for the domain name, easy to remember and it's already appearing in connection with TeX.

Comment: @John: is that good or bad?

Answer (score 24):

Although something in imitation of Stack Overflow (*a la* Math Overflow) is possible, in Joel Spolsky's [post on domain names](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/), he recommends choosing something meaningful to the community, just as Stack Overflow means something to programmers.

If we want to stay with the overflow theme with a TeX twist, though, I suggest:

## overfull hbox

Comment: As is pointed out for another good TeX-based idea, the problem is 'will the non-expert find this'. Experienced (La)TeX users know about overfull hboxes, but most users looking for advice may not do. That said, it is a nice name :-)

Comment: @Joseph How many programmers nowadays suffer from stack overflow (ok, infinite recursion, but it is not so common)? Most people will find this site by googling some TeX related question, so the name is irrelevant here.

Comment: Since it should be a domain, I suggest HboxOverfull.com... free!

Comment: I think this one is good -- I mean, pretty much everyone has seen TeX tell you "overfull hbox", even if she didn't understand what's the point of the message.

Comment: I think it's a bad name. It isn't obvious at all. Yes, it is a common warning to get, but it doesn't **sound** like a website name, much less like a Tex Q&A site.

The main criteria is **not** "is it named after a TeX error", but "is it a good website name". And I don't think it is.

Comment: Also, multi-word names aren't ideal. I have to remember whether it is overfull-hbox or overfullhbox or hboxoverfull. Shorten it to overfull.com (and get hold of the domain), and I think it'd work really well.

Comment: Of all of the suggestions so far, this and the badness10000 one are the only ones which raise a smile.  Yes, the domain doesn't _have_ to be named after an error, but it will look wryly familiar to almost all users of *TeX.  overfullhbox.com, overfullhbox.com, ... it has a ring to it.

Comment: @jalf: This was mostly a humorous suggestion so I'm not going to defend it, but about multi-word names: consider Stack Overflow, Super User, Server Fault, Math Overflow, and [most existing Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites). :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: I know, but those names are easy to see/pronounce as a single word. It's pretty common to see people refer to the sites as StackOverflow, Superuser. overfullhbox doesn't work quite as well in a single word. ;)

Comment: My pick of the bunch. It's clever and relevant, has clear "StackOverflow" connotations, and has a uniqueness and charm that names like "TeXnique.com" lack.

Answer (score 13):

## TeXSupport.com

Taken.

eh? eh?

Has a default install of IIS7 on it, looks like it is a home PC, or something...

---

Actually, I just noticed that this works whether or not you know how to pronounce "TeX".

Noobs will get the name of the site right. :)

Comment: Corny but oh so appropriate ;-) If we can get access to the domain, I like it.

Comment: A perfect name. :-)

Comment: I think it's ok, except or one thing. "Support" might imply too much, well, support. If I have problems with my TeX install, I might call support and *demand* they fix my problem, kind of thing. The site is for community Q&A, not official support. This name might mislead beginners though.

Comment: -1 from me: it does suggest a more 'solve my problem now!' interaction, less a peer-to-peer thing.  Also, inverting David's remark, it's appropriate, but oh so corny.

Answer (score 12):

## TeXnicians.com

(or something similar). Taken.

IIRC, Knuth mentions the word "texnician" near the beginning of the TeXbook, where he explains how to pronounce TeX (asking "texnician" or "texpert"?)

Comment: +Over9000: This is a great name, but it seems to be taken.

Comment: Oh, sad. Perhaps texnicians.net? (Though .com is always better…) Or drop the s? Too bad if all are taken.

Comment: Why not TeXperts.com? It's free.

Comment: @mbq:  Because that is an improper pronunciation of the name 'TeX'.  It is pronounced 'tech'.  'Techperts'?

Comment: Sounds fine if you're Scottish.

Comment: @John Gietzen: puns get poetic license.

Comment: @John I know about the pronunciation, yet this word appears in the TeX world.

Answer (score 8):

## texoverflow.com

An obvious choice would of course be `texoverflow.com`, which happens to also be available.

Comment: Yep, that's probably my favorite so far. It's obvious what the site is about just from the name, *and* it's clear from the name that it's a sibling of StackOverflow. People who know SO will know just from the name what `texoverflow.com` is, and it has a nice ring to it as a name, as something you might be able to remember, or write down, or pronounce over the phone.

Comment: It might be worth editing this to make the suggestion as large as all the others -- not sure if it's getting passed over in quick scans down the list...

Comment: I haven't downvoted this, but I don't like this name. Not many beginning TeX users know of Stack Overflow (which was partly a reason to create this website in the first place, instead of continuing to ask just LaTeX questions there), so there's not much to be gained that wouldn't be apparent from one look at the website interface. And I'd prefer domain names to be something meaningful to TeX, rather than merely *-Overflow (though ["Sink Overflow"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites) is hilarious).

Answer (score 8):

## TeXnobabble.com

Don't blame me; I was solicited to post this by somebody not in the private beta!

Comment: I have to say I kind of like it :P

Answer (score 8):

## ten.pt

Notwithstanding the suggestion that `.com` domains should be preferred, `ten.pt` has a sly reference to typesetting, and would certainly be memorable.

There's no A record attached to the domain, though it does appear to be registered as an SOA record.

There may be other problems, since the [ccTLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.pt) has some restrictions on second-level domains.  If this were attractive, though, I'm sure these could be investigated.

Answer (score 7):

## badness10000.com

Comment: goodness10000.com might be more optimistic (or goodness10000.org?).  I like it, but if you know enough to about TeX to get the joke, you might not have too many questions needing answered.

Comment: -1: Even people who know what it means in terms of LaTeX might have trouble figuring out what it means just by looking that the domain name.

Comment: @Norman, perhaps we can aspire to a high level of questions and answers, such as experts who know what badness 10000 means might find interesting! (I'm a shameless elitist, being one of the hardline experts-only moderators on MathOverflow. :-)

Comment: This is a beautiful name.

Comment: Even an expert who knows what badness 10000 means is more likely to assume this domain name to be some sleazy link farm or similar. It sounds like "I'm registering 8000 different domains based on random words, cramming them full of ads, and using it for SEO)

Comment: @Scott having taken a look at MathOverflow, I've a clearer idea what you mean, and I think I disagree with you about the ideal level of question.  I think yours is a good position w.r.t. MathOverflow (it's clear there's a need for quite technical maths questions, not catered for elsewhere), but there's a need for an arena for the _full_ range of LaTeX questions, from 'what package does X?' to questions about `\afterassignment`.  Indeed, the top end of that range is potentially best catered for by comp.text.tex.  (perhaps this discussion should be in a different question!)

Answer (score 6):

## BoxesAndGlue.com

my favorite features of TeX layout!

Comment: Very clever name! I'd give +1000 for it, if I could :)

Answer (score 5):

## TeXnocracy.com

It's available, and it also subtly hints at Scott Morrison's elitist vision for the site (which I suppose is either a good thing or a bad thing, depending on your viewpoint).

Answer (score 4):

TeXAnswers

## TeXAnswers.com

Yes,  **available!**
Infinitely memorable. Direct and to the point.
Even if you don't know the correct pronunciation, you're going to "get" this.

Answer (score 4):

## TeXy.com

TeX is sexy, and the site's name should reflect that sentiment.

Answer (score 3):

Isn’t it [perfectly obvious](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/03/whos-your-arch-enemy.html)?

## expertexchange.com

alternative spelling:

## exper-texchange.com

Honestly, everything else would disappoint me.

<sub>(No, not a serious suggestion!)</sub>

Comment: texpert-sexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

In a comment to the TeXnique.com answer, John Gietsen wrote: *This domain name is now taken... BY STACK OVERFLOW INTERNET SERVICES!* .  Is that good or bad?

I started a new answer mostly to push this question up in the 'active' list, but also:

## TeXnicians.org

is free at the moment.

Comment: It’s good. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

## texmf-qa.com

**available**

Word play on texmf install trees. This reflects on expert side of customising and advanced usage of all things *TeX* world. The non-standard -qa suffix reflects the purpose of the site and welcomes beginner users to ask basic questions as well. **QA** stands for *questions & answers* as well as *quality assurance* bridging the gap between novice and experts in the typography field.

Comment: +1 for originality (and I actually do like this)

Comment: I also like having the neglected Metafont reflected in the title.

Answer (score 2):

## TeXperts.com

I like it at least in part because of the site that shall not be named.

Comment: +1 I was first with that.

Comment: Sure (though neither of us is the first to have though of it, I'd wager.) But, your mention was buried in a comment, so I thought it better to suggest it following Larry's sensible suggestion on the OP.

Answer (score 2):

## UseTeX.org

Short, I own it.

Answer (score 1):

**TeXknowledge.com**

A wordplay on technology, easy to remember and descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

## GetTeXnical.com

Available, topical... snazzy?

Answer (score 0):

## TeXnologists.com

Though, I fear that this excludes Scott Hanselman...

Comment: Might just be me, but this one kind of reminded me of 'scientologists', which probably isn't the ideal association to make. ;)

Answer (score -3):

## TeXHelp.com

Simple, and very similar to TeXSupport, but I think it won't encourage people to ask about TeX installation problems. We offer help, not technical support :)

Answer (score -7):

## Everything.You.Ever.Wanted.To.Know.About.TeX.But.Were.Afraid.To.Ask.com

(sorry, sorry, I'll hide back in my cave again)

Comment: Good luck getting Ask.com to give up the subdomain. ;)