# Should there be a wiki question for inserting figures into LaTeX?

Tags: discussion

I am not really sure if this really is a good idea as I have expressed in chat, so I thought of asking here to know the opinion of the community.

This recent question [Inserting Images in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99531/inserting-images-in-latex) which was closed as a duplicate, which is in turn a duplicate, might be considered a *basic* question--one in which an answer can be readily had and in more detail in freely-available manual like [`lshort`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lshort). I did some searching and found out an old [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134187/how-to-add-a-jpg-image-in-latex) posted some time ago about including `.jpg` files.

This might not be the first time that a question about inclusion of an external graphics will pop up so I am thinking that we can write a wiki question that summarizes basic inclusion of external graphics and close the other questions as duplicate of this wiki question. I am not sure though if this is the right approach.

So this post have two subquestions:

- Do we go with creating this wiki question?
- If we do, what should be included in the wiki question and answer? (Inserting `.eps` files and the use of `graphicx` package, etc.)

Comment: In my view, learning through illustration would be simple and attractive. Pasting some link with some example in [writelatex](https://www.writelatex.com/74051skkgcl) may help

Answer (score 6):

This idea of having simple, moderately general questions to serve as a good question for several trivial questions to be marked duplicates of, is what I argued for in my answer to https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3299/175.

I'm undecided on the merits of making these community wiki.  IIRC, that requires a moderator intervention.

Comment: I see that my question is just a subset of the question in your metal link. And I can see that I even voted your question up. That post pretty much summed up what I want to do, although my question is specific to including graphics and what should be included in the Q and A. I am afraid my meta post may be a duplicate. :)

Comment: @hpesoj626 - No, the wiki angle is something I hadn't thought of.  It might be nice to get some modrator input to this question.

Comment: Well, it should definitely be wiki since in many cases, even of the `\includegraphics` case, the new post will be a summary of the others. And so improving the questions and answers should be a "community" undertaking from the start. My fear is just that expressed T. Verron, that there is a danger our Q and A will parallel the manuals, which is not the purpose of this site. Although I have in mind the total newbies who are more used to searching answers through google than to going directly to manuals that they know nothing about yet in the first place.

Comment: @hpesoj626 - I think what is involved in creating high quality FAQ-like answers is maybe done better on an individual basis, rather than on a wiki basis.  I've been unimpressed by the results achieved via "communal" answers on SX outside of tag wikis and meta.

Comment: I see your point although I have to admit that I have not considered it until now that you mentioned it.