# About "trivial" answers

Tags: discussion, answers

An obvious spinoff of the wonderful '[About "trivial" questions](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3298/about-trivial-questions),' but different in intent.

I'm still relatively new here, but I've been around long enough to see that a whole ton of potential answers (mostly in the form of 'have you tried this' or 'have you seen this package') are said in comments rather than in actual, votable answers.  I recognize that more than a few of these answers won't do what the asker actually intends to do; they are very useful in actually making the answer more precise (and thus more answerable in general).  That said, a lot of these answers would be good answers anyways, regardless of the asker's fancy.

We know that comments are very different from answers; the best ones don't exactly get 'voted to the top' as it were.  Comments should be focused on focusing the question, not answering it... right?

I ask this mostly because I would have felt bad in these [two](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100006) [scenarios](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100004) with a one-line answer - some things just don't feel like they're worth making an 'answer' when they really do qualify.

Comment: We've had some recent discussion of this here: [Why do people answer in comments?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3238/2693).

Comment: It looks like I was searching for the wrong thing -- this was exactly my question (and a ton of great discussion!)