# Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline

Tags: discussion

*We closed the [domain naming thread (click for details)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14/what-should-our-domain-name-be).*

Instead, **let's start with a killer "elevator pitch!"** Joel will be blogging about the elevator pitch approach to naming, but to get you started:

### The Elevator Pitch

This isn't as easy as it sounds. Imagine the user who will never read your FAQ and you have two seconds to grab their attention. It should be catchy but descriptive. It should be thoroughly clear but painfully concise. **Make every... word... count.**

Here are some creative examples:

- [Gawker](http://gawker.com/): Daily Manhattan media news and gossip. Reporting live from the center of the universe.
- [Gizmodo](http://gizmodo.com/): The gadget guide. So much in love with shiny new toys, it’s unnatural.
- [Autoblog](http://www.autoblog.com/): We obsessively cover the auto industry.
- [DumbLittleMan](http://www.dumblittleman.com/): So what do we do here? Well, it’s simple. 15 to 20 times per week we provide tips that will save you money, increase your productivity, or simply keep you sane.
- [Needcoffee.com](http://www.needcoffee.com/): We are the Internet equivalent of a triple espresso with whipped cream. Mmmm…whipped cream.

### Use it as a Tagline

A shorter elevator pitch *can* be used as a tagline — something you can display in the header at the top of the page. If it doesn't fit, consider shortening it or creating a separate tagline. Here are some great examples:

- [Slashdot](http://slashdot.org/): News for nerds. Stuff that matters.
- [Lifehacker](http://www.lifehacker.com/): Don’t live to geek, geek to live!
- [The Simple Dollar](http://www.thesimpledollar.com/): Financial talk for the rest of us.

### The Motto (don't forget your logo)

A logo begs for it own little, short tagline — like a motto. Maybe the tagline inspires the logo; Maybe it's the other way around. Mottos make good t-shirt, bumper stickers, and other marketing material. Either way, you'll recognize a good motto when you see it:

- Just do it.
- Think Different.
- The Uncola.
- Intel inside.
- Like a rock.
- The king of beers.

…and perhaps all this leads to a proper name and domain for your site… *eventually*. So let's start from the basics. **Come up with a killer elevator pitch, tagline, and/or motto!**

Comment: Care to make this a community wiki? Seems we'd better work on and improve only a few proposals instead of each rolling their own. The pitch/tagline/motto should be something that everybody can identify with, after all.

Comment: This is actually one of those times when a chat room would be of great help </hint>.

Answer (score 6):

I believe in simplicity and directness. Therefore:

Motto:

> ### Typesetting TeXt

or, alternatively:

> ### Typesetting TeXniques

(Obviously, both should be using the actual TeX logo, not some ASCII convolution.)

Tagline / elevator pitch:

> **How to create beautiful documents using TeX and friends**

(Hat tip to @domwass)

Comment: I like the “Typesetting TeXnique”, although “Typesetting TeXniques” might be even better. (And, obviously, I like the tagline (c; )

Comment: @domwass: Yes, I wasn’t sure about “texnique” vs. “texniques” myself. I’ve changed it now.

Answer (score 4):

I kind of liked the originally “chosen” domain name. So here it goes a suggestion for something like a ... tagline?

### TeXnique for your typesetting needs.

Comment: One could combine it with the runner-up domain name: *Overfull boxes of TeXnique for your typesetting needs.*

Answer (score 2):

### TeXnique – How to create beautiful documents

Answer (score 2):

Riffing off a couple of similar suggestions:

### TeX & Friends: beautiful documents, semantic markup.

So perhaps instead

### TeX & Friends: sensible markup for beautiful documents

I don't like the adjective "beautiful" here but I cant think of a good alternative.

Comment: Just a note: some people might quibble with the description of TeX as semantic markup. I was at the AMS/MAA joint maths conference last year, and went to a "Web 2.0" (or something like that) special session. When I asked them "why should a mathematician care what you are doing when TeX is more well known and also semantic", they looked at me like I'm from outerspace, and launched a schpiel on the overloading of `^` for multiple different semantic purposes...

Comment: Maybe ‘sane markup’? There's a big difference between "semantic" and "so semantic it's impossible to type by hand".

Comment: This is the first time I hear somebody calling TeX markup "sane"...

Comment: Markup != proramming! Woukd you rather type your documents in TeX or XML? The real strength of LaTeX markup and similar is that they're designed to be used for *writing*.

Comment: @willie: in LaTeX strictly speaking ^ is unambiguous, I think. But the abstraction to TeX is leaky and the other uses for ^ poke through. But point taken.

Comment: @Will Robertson: just to parrot what I was told (so please don't shoot the messenger), "^ in math mode means 'raise to the exponent', 'upper limit of integration/summation', as well as 'indices in Einstein notation', and sometimes 'the number of derivatives to take'." Apparently (!) that in a semantic markup, each one of those should be associated to a different command. (BTW: perfectly agree that the real strength of LaTeX is that it is designed for writing, and thus efforts to push unnecessarily verbose semantic markups will ultimately fail to convert a wide audience.)

Comment: @willie—thanks for the examples, you're totally right. FWIW, I like packages like `cool` that define commands like `\Integral{f(x)}{x_1}{x_2}` that apply a semantic layer onto (some of) maths without interfering with the ease of writing it.

Comment: I like your suggestion. Perhaps in combination with "structured documents" instead of "markup"? But I can't think of another wording right now.

Comment: +1, It captures two good arguments for Tex* in one tagline.  Worry: I wonder just how large a demographic will both be atrracted by the idea, and (per Willie) will find it convincing on second thought.

Comment: @Willie Wong: I was at that session too!  We should meet up if you are in New Orleans this year.  And although you were treated brusquely, I do agree with Bill and Tom there: as far as math notation goes, TeX is not semantic.  LaTeX does a better job (compared to plain) of semantic document markup, but the the math is not.

Comment: @Matthew: I fully agree the (largely TeX-based) math markup in LaTeX can't be described as "semantic". Not sure what I was thinking above. Something to work on for the future...

Comment: @Matthew Leingang: I haven't quite decided whether I'll be in New Orleans yet. I'll drop you a line if I do decide to go. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

motto:

#### Got TeXnique?

Answer (score 2):

As for the motto:

### Every TeX counts

That is, to give the idea that this site is about **TeX**, La**TeX**, Con**TeX**t,... Can you see the pattern? :)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, this doesn't look so good written down as when it was in my head, but maybe someone else can improve on it:

### tex.SX: the site that helps you make your paper look as good as its contents.

Take 2:

### Beautiful documents for your smart ideas.

(although with TeX&co. it's often more like **“Ugly hacks for your beautiful documents”** :P).

Comment: +1 OK idea.  How about: "Texnique.com: Make your print as good as your content"?  The FAQ obviously needs a section, **“Ugly hacks for your beautiful documents”**

Answer (score 1):

### Texnique.com: DIY Document Preparation for the Connoisseur

This doesn't quite hit the sweet spot for me —words like connoisseur, discriminating, &c. have slight unwanted associations—  but I'm keen on the idea of combining both DIY and superior results into the tagline, if it can be done well.  This way, it becomes a pitch for what makes us care about Tex at the same time as being a memorable phrase for the site.

**Take 2:**

### TeXnique.com: DIY Document Preparation for both Connoisseur and Apprentice.

Added some extra in the end to stress on the non-elite nature of tex.SE

Comment: Hmm, we could extend it just a bit not to look like some high-brow-TeX-elite-hackers-only site.

Comment: @mindcorrosive: Yes, "elitist", "snobbish", and "not for greasy oiks like you" are some of the unwanted connotations of connoisseur.  Take #2 is definitely better in this respect, but it's rather too unwieldy for a tag line.

Comment: @mindcorrosive: German has the magic word "profi" that means professional, DIY, and "great results", that drives millions of German males between the ages of 35 and 65 to buy large quantities of overpriced, over-engineered, unneeded power tools.  When we roll out "texnique.de", I'll have just the tagline for the site.  Shame I can't find anything as good in English.

Answer (score 0):

**TeXnique.com:**

### Finest quality in typesetting. Techniques for typography gourmets.

Take 2:

### Techniques for typography gourmets. Dotting the i's and crossing the t's since 2010.

Comment: Can't shake the feeling of a clause missing, as in "typography gourmets and [ witty group description]"

Comment: Feel free to improve it. :-)  It's not my 1st language.

Comment: Should that be “TeXniques”?

Comment: How are these suggestions also not appropriate to, say, a site dedicated to Adobe Indesign?

Comment: @Will: Good point – the magic word "DIY" is more appropriate for Tex than Indesign, hence my answer.  Now ... why do you use camel case for Latex and not Indesign – double standards, I call it!

Comment: Stefan: I prefer take #1 to #2.  "Techniques for typography" has nice alliteration; I'm not sure that "gourmet" actually adds anything to the tagline: we already start we "finest quality".  Maybe "Gourmet typesetting – Techniques for typography" is better?  But that still leaves Will's objection.

Comment: @Charles: camelcase is slightly too much effort on an iPad :-) but muscle memory is growing for TeX etc.

Comment: @Will: There's a question waiting to burst out of that comment – Which Ipad text editor is least demanding on muscle memory when writing Latex or Mathjax?

Answer (score 0):

This'll wind up all MetaPost and ConTeXT devotees, and probably a few others, but it's just a silly suggestion for a motto:

## TikZ, Toc, TeX

Not sure how to turn it into a tagline, though.

### TikZ, toc, TeX.SX: the site that makes your documents run like clockwork

### TikZ, toc, TeX.SX, and makeindex: Make your documents run like clockwork

Comment: -1: It's fun, but I wouldn't like the site to use it.

Answer (score -1):

### Texnique.com: Freedom from Adobe and Office

*Second try*

Inspired by Jeff's message, *if you have an arch-enemy – the more ... larger-than-life the better – consider yourself lucky*, from [Coding Horror: Who's Your Arch-Enemy?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/03/whos-your-arch-enemy.html).  Don't vote this up unless you've thought about the risk of groupthink and alienating exactly the people we want to attract.  Jeff's comment

> I have absolutely nothing against Experts-Exchange. Realize that I've been a fan of the [smackdown learning model](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000630.html) for a long time; it's like [kayfabe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kayfabe) in professional wrestling. There are no hard feelings; this "rivalry" is mostly useful as a way to explain what it is we do. This internet is certainly big enough for the both of us – big enough, in fact, for hundreds of Q&A websites.

seems to be a wise counter to that risk; if we use this tagline, we'll need a carefully worded section in the FAQ.

## Alternatives

### Texnique.com: Writing without the help of Office or Adobe

*First try, too wordy*

Comment: Except of course that pdfTeX generates files in a format that was invented by and is still mostly controlled by Adobe.

Comment: @Caramdir: PDF 1.7 is an ISO standard.